# Appending an item to an array with a variable key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to append to a Javascript array in a loop.

I am writing this:

```
        var total_val = (unemployment_multi + laws_multi + family_multi + mobility_multi) / 5;
            country_vals.push({total_val:key});
```

But I end up having a bunch of objects with total_val as the key, rather than the value of total_val.

How do I create an array key with the value that is in total_val? Would I do something like country_vals.total_val.key or something?

EDIT: My goal is to have all of the values in `total_val` sortable by number - it is going to be a number from 1-10, and I want to sort in order of lowest to highest or highest to low (doesn't matter which), and each will have at least one of the `key` variable attached to it, but possibly more than one.

Comment: What do you mean by _"Array key"_?

Comment: you want [40,89, 13]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
country_vals[total_val] = key
```

Or:

```
total_val = ''+total_val
country_vals.push({total_val:key});
```

Comment: Does not the first one give a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`?

Comment: The problem is that I may want to have more than one value per total_val.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander could you show us a basic example of the data structure you want to create written as a literal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to create an object with dynamic keys

```
var total_val = (unemployment_multi + laws_multi + family_multi + mobility_multi) / 5;
var obj = {};
obj[total_val] = key;
country_vals.push(obj);
```